# How can you use Angular's canActivate to negate the result of a guard?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, canactivate, angular-guards

[From the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) on `canActivate`, it seems you can only use `canActivate` guards to allow proceeding to a route if the `canActivate` function ultimately returns `true`.

Is there some way to say, "only proceed to this route if the `canActivate` class evaluates to `false`" ?

For example, to not allow logged in users to visit the log in page, I tried this but it did not work:

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
    { path: 'log-in', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [ !UserLoggedInGuard ] },
```

I got this error in the console:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[false]: 
  StaticInjectorError[false]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for false!
Error: StaticInjectorError[false]: 
  StaticInjectorError[false]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for false!
```

Comment: you cant negate a type, thats completely wrong

Comment: With this particular case of the login page. I make a totally separate guard, something like `AuthRedirectGuard` which checks if the user is logged in. If true, redirect to the landing page, else continue to login.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The interesting thing in your question is the formulation:

> Is there some way to say, "only proceed to this route if the
>   **canActivate class evaluates to false**" ?

And how you expressed the "intuitive" solution:

```
{ path: 'log-in', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [ !UserLoggedInGuard ] },
```

Which basically says, you need to `negate` the result of `UserLoggedInGuard@canActivate`

Lets consider the following implementation of the `UserLoggedInGuard`:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserLoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {
   constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {}

   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return this._authService.isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

Next, lets look at the solution proposed by @Mike

```
@Injectable()
export class NegateUserLoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {    
    constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {}

   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return !this._authService.isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

Now, the approach is ok, but is tightly coupled to the (internal) implementation of `UserLoggedInGuard` . If for some reason the implementation of `UserLoggedInGuard@canActivate` changes, `NegateUserLoggedInGuard` will break.

How can we avoid that? Simple, abuse dependency injection:

```
@Injectable()
export class NegateUserLoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {    
  constructor(private _userLoggedInGuard: UserLoggedInGuard) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
     return !this._userLoggedInGuard.canActivate(route,state);
  }
}
```

Now this is doing **exactly** what you expressed with

```
canActivate: [ !UserLoggedInGuard ]
```

And the best part:

- It isnt tightly coupled with the internal implementation of the `UserLoggedInGuard`
- Can be expanded to manipulate the result of more than one `Guard` class

Comment: Great idea. I would also put both exported classes in the same file, and maybe make the actual `canActivate` function definition a separate external function common between them

Comment: I dont really see a good reason to share the implemention through a function. I would simply use DI to compose this negate guard wrapper

Comment: I also wouldnt suggest to put both classes in one file. What if the negation guard now negates the result of more than one guard? In which file would you put it?

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: This however doesn't work when the 'isLoggedIn' method returns an Observable

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem - wanted to make a login page that was only accessible if not authenticated and a dashboard only accessible if you are authenticated (and redirect user to appropriate one automatically). I solved it by making the guard itself login+route sensitive:

The Routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

The Guard:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  private login: UrlTree;
  private dash: UrlTree;

  constructor(private authSvc: AuthenticationService, private router: Router ) {
    this.login = this.router.parseUrl('login');
    this.dash = this.router.parseUrl('dashboard');
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree {
    if (this.authSvc.isSignedIn()) {
      if (route.routeConfig.path === 'login') {
        return this.dash;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      if (route.routeConfig.path === 'login') {
        return true;
      } else {
        return this.login;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about your problem, one solution could be to implement a route guard that does the logic in reverse.

```
import { MyService } from "./myservice.service";
import { CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        return this.myService.isNotLoggedIn(); //if user not logged in this is true
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically creating a completely separate guard for the `not` situation ?

Comment: @CodyBugstein exactly since you want the reverse

Comment: Right, this is the solution I'm using right now. But it's not an ideal solution since I'll have to double my amount of guards and have a lot of duplicated code

Comment: there's no way around it man :( unless you want in the service to make a bool `isNotLoggedIn` and use that to evaluate your normal guard?

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: sorry bro, nada I can thinks, but if this is sufficient mind picking this and calling it a day? :)

Answer (score 0):

I added a `data.auth: boolean` option to all of my routes (except the ones that should be accessible either way), like so:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', // all
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'authenticate', // not authenticated
    component: AuthComponent,
    data: { auth: false },
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'account', // authenticated
    component: AccountComponent,
    data: { auth: true },
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
]
```

And then in my auth guard, I check for this data property and act accordingly:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly supabase: SupabaseService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return route.data['auth'] ? !!this.supabase.session : !this.supabase.session
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put data in guards

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
    canActivate: [isAuthenticatedGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadComponent: () => import('./modules/login/login.component').then(m => m.LoginComponent),
    canActivate: [isAuthenticatedGuard],
    data: { disableAccess: true }
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    loadComponent: () => import('./modules/register/register.component').then(m => m.RegisterComponent),
    canActivate: [isAuthenticatedGuard],
    data: { disableAccess: true }
  }
```

[image: data and property name is disableAccess, decided that allowAccess name for property is not good]
code:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    const url: string = state.url;
    const result = this.checkLogin(url);
    const { disableAccess = false } = route.data;
    const redirectMessage =
      "User is not logged - This routing guard prevents redirection to any routes that needs logging."; // TODO: Move it out

    if (result) {
      if (disableAccess) {
        console.log(redirectMessage);
        this.router.navigate(['home/main',]); //TODO: redirect to logout, and prepare application for logout
      }
    } else {
      console.log(redirectMessage);
      if (!disableAccess) {
        this.router.navigate(['login',]); //TODO: redirect to logout, and prepare application for logout
      }
    }

    return disableAccess ? !result : result;
  }
```

And then just manipulate with it like this, or any other way
[image]

First: solution to create new guard and reuse canActivate from opposite guard is obviously bad.
There can be redirects which can be triggered from another guard, and in general idea to inject guard to another guard - not fine.

Will glad to see your comments if you have any words for me.